# Different CSS styles for each category page

Tags: magento2

Magento community!
Today I find myself with a task quite simple in my opinion but due to my little experience in Magento 2, I am not finding a way to apply different CSS styles for each category page.
I need to give a height of different pixels to the container that builds the banner-slider for each category of my store since in category A the image of the banner looks perfect, but in category B as well as in category C the image of the banner is overlaid by another container that is displayed below it.
Thank you! I hope that some enlightened one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check on your category page body classes you got one different for each category pages like **category-Your category name/URL-key** so you use that class as a parent class and do different CSS for all the pages banner as per your requirement.